# pickle class that is dynamically constructed using `type`

Tags: python, oop, pickle

I have a situation where I have a base class, a mixin class and a couple of child classes. I want to dynamically add the mixin classs' functionality in an OOP fashion; note that the mixin overrides some of the base class methods. I want to have the following OOP patterns:

Case 1: `base <- child1`, `base <- child2`... 
Case 2: `base <- mixin <- child1`, `base <- mixin <- child2`

I solved this by using `python` builtin function [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type). The problem with doing so is that the newly created class cannot have attribute lookup for pickle (see code below). ***Question***: how do I pickle a class that was dynamically created using `type(...)`?

I also have a lingering feeling that the dynamic inheritance/ class construction is not very often used and is a bit ugly. Suggestions on better code style are also more than welcome.

```
import pickle

class Base:
    pass

class MixIn(Base):
    pass

class Child1(Base):
    pass

class Child2(Base):
    pass
 
mbc1 = type('BaseMixChild1', (Child1, MixIn), {})()  # this is instance of a class with the extra functionality
mbc2 = type('BaseMixChild2', (Child2, MixIn), {})()  # "..." 
child1 = Child1()  # this is instance of only base functionality

pickle.dumps(child1)  # clearly no problem
pickle.dumps(mbc1)  # problem!
```

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.BaseMixChild1'>: attribute lookup BaseMixChild1 on __main__ failed
```

Comment: Why not just create the classes statically? `class BaseMixChild1(Child1, Mixin): pass`

Comment: have you tried [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/)?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica OMG thank you! I feel a little embarrassed even haha, but that is indeed the best solution I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As per the solution of [user2357112 supports Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica), I just created a static class: `class BaseMixChild1(Child1, Mixin): pass`. Since attribute lookup is now possible, this works. This does not address the dynamic class construction + pickling issue but is indeed a solution for my current problem.